# Deleting duplicate rows, keeping most recent row by max(datetime)

Tags: mysql, duplicates

The MySQL statement below selects all rows that have duplicates based on ADDRESS1 and POSTCODE of which the most recent row, INSPECTION_DATE. Essentially it selects all the ones I want to keep.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(INSPECTION_DATE), ADDRESS1, POSTCODE, id
FROM epc 
GROUP BY ADDRESS1, POSTCODE 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

My question is, how do I delete all of the older duplicates, keeping the ones that the above statement returns.

Comment: It's often quicker to construct a new table with just the data you want to keep and then effectively 'overwrite' the old table with the new one.

Comment: @Strawberry All the data was already there when imported. I didn't want to overwrite data, I want to delete the old data so that it is optimised going forward. Adding data to it in the future I will of course just overwrite existing data

Comment: I don't see the difference - but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Ah right, I see what you're saying. So you mean create a new table with the max(INSPECTION_DATE) ones rather than select all of the older duplicates and delete them

Comment: Well, yes, that is what I said !?!

Comment: @Strawberry I guess. "Overwrite the old table with the new one" was what threw me off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8de866/1

```
DELETE  e
FROM epc e
INNER JOIN epc max_
ON e.address1 = max_.address1
   AND e.postcode = max_.postcode
   AND e.inspection_date < max_.inspection_date;
```

**UPDATE** 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bd5981/1

```
DELETE  e
FROM epc e
INNER JOIN epc max_
ON e.address1 = max_.address1
   AND e.postcode = max_.postcode
   AND (e.inspection_date < max_.inspection_date
        OR (e.inspection_date = max_.inspection_date
           AND e.id < max_.id));
```

Comment: Anyway of making this more efficient? It will be doing a full table scan due to checking each INSPECTION_DATE and I have 13 million rows in there. Thanks

Comment: You mean that doing `MAX()` and `COUNT()` server does not scan the table? And even when you have `max_value`, don't we still need to scan the table to find all `val < max_val` anyway?

Comment: I've just ran the statement exactly as you put it above and let it run... after 609 seconds, I got "0 row(s) affected"

But, if I run:
`SELECT COUNT(*), ADDRESS1, POSTCODE, id
FROM epc
GROUP BY ADDRESS1, POSTCODE 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;` I get a lot of results back with all the duplicates still

Any ideas?

Comment: If you did it **exactly** as I posted - you are kind not telling me truth, since I have my fiddle provided. Please provide your set of data - where my query will fail, and we can discuss *why* then.

Comment: I know, I feel as confused. I ran your code against the SQLFiddle and it worked for me too. But when I run it on my table, I get that. I'll get more data for you 1 min

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/THmv9Ye.png - Check the screenshot. You can see the column names exist, the query that returned them and also your statement above at the bottom returning 0 results. Thanks

Comment: so what is return of `SELECT * FROM epc WHERE address1='(Adams) AND id=2563599 AND postcode='DH9 8TE'` ?

Comment: Only 1 row because ID is unique. If I remove the id from the statement and only address1 and postcode then I get 2 rows. `SELECT * FROM epc WHERE address1='(Adams)' AND postcode='DH9 8TE'` = 2 rows returned

Comment: Ah, I need to test another one. For some reason INSPECTION_DATE is the same for those 2 rows

Comment: No you don't. You need to decide what to do when date is the same?

Comment: Yeah I just needed to ensure that they were all the same to confirm that was the issue and it is

Comment: Could you help me with the next statement please? I just want to randomly delete all duplicates with the same date but keep 1 of them